# google maps add bounce to multiple markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I'm having an issue here trying to add "bounce" to a clicked marker on Google maps API v3 when I've loaded in multiple markers, just like google do in this example:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations
I essentially want to combine that example, with this one :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration

Here is what I have so far:
http://codepen.io/lexbi/pen/DkKmu/

The difference being is that the bounce seems to be initiated on the "Marker" variable, but I am not able to get that because I'm putting all of my markers into an array.

Has anyone got any suggestions on how I can re-work this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

inside the `click`-listener of a marker you may access the `Marker`-object via `this` , no need to access them via `markers`